# Reference to a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code

```
var $div = $('<div/>');

$('#blah').after($div);
```

This works. However, I would like to make it a one-liner. Something like this:

```
var $div = $('<div/>')
                .closest('#wrapper')
                .find('#blah')
                .after(this); //<-- point to the div element
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be creating a `div` and then looking *within* that created `div` for another element (which isn't there, since you've not created it). Can you give an accurate idea of the HTML structure you're working with?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yea my bad. Should have added something like `.closest()` before and selecting the wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the [**`insertAfter(target)`**](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) method? It returns the original jQuery object, rather than the target.

```
var $div = $('<div />').insertAfter('#blah');
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/K3btf/)

Comment: The `insertAfter()` function will take a selector string, so you can just do `insertAfter('#blah')`, rather than passing it a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

try add end();

```
var $div = $('<div/>')
                .find('#blah').end()
                .after(this);
```

Comment: I don't want to run after() on the div itself. end() doesn't make any sense here.